# Flagging answers on closed questions?

Tags: support, answers, flagging

Just came across this question: [Scheduled Tasks - Display the script](https://superuser.com/questions/521566/scheduled-tasks-display-the-script). The OP might have accepted that "answer" since it pointed him to the proper solution, but clearly a link to a previous SU post isn't suitable as an answer. Turns out the person who posted the SU link as an answer (instead of a comment) was also the first person to mark the question as a duplicate using that same link.

Considering the question has been closed, does it make sense to flag the accepted response as "not an answer"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, links to other Super User questions/answers aren't real answers—at least if they don't go beyond what's stated there and simply say, "Look here, here's your answer". We'd delete those anyway, and possibly close the question as a duplicate.

Normally we don't delete accepted answers, but in this case the person who answered also voted to close the question as a duplicate, so I'd say: flag away in such cases.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!